# How to get Sublime's autocomplete on VSCode? (ie: typing <link and pressing tab to autocomplete it)

Tags: visual-studio-code

e: youtube answered to me in a random video, apparently I need to install "snippets"

I'm loving VSCode but I despise it's tag completion capabilities and I find Sublime much easier to type.

When I type "link" on Sublime it autocompletes to 
    link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=""> for example

or the way I skip towards the end of the tag when I press Tab.

Is there anyway to get this on VSCode? I don't want to go back to Sublime

Comment: So when you type "link" in an html file, you do not get any suggestions that pop up?  What version of vscode are you using?

Comment: I get a suggestion to complete the link tag with a tool symbol, but it only completes the link word. I'm using the last version in every software since I downloaded it this week. Windows 10

Comment: Do you have this setting available:  "emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "always", ? If not, you do not have the most recent version of vscode. Or have you disabled editor.quickSuggestions - that would kill the emmet suggestions as well.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet in general.  But if you do not have emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation available or set to always then make sure you are on v1.24.1.  Assuming you are in a supported file type.

Comment: I read that article and also reinstalled it.
link tag works better, script tag still the same
thanks for the help! but I'll give up :P

Answer (score 1):

Install vscode intelliSense extension for your language or framework to achieve this autocomplete effect

Answer (score 0):

You can get pretty close to what you showed by typing `link:css` and then expanding the Emmet suggestion you get from that. VS Code comes with [a builtin Emmet extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/emmet). You can find official user docs for it at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet. See also https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/.